# "Numeric Puzzles" in Latex. Vertical division etc. with letters and other symbols

Tags: lists, tikz-styles, xlop

I tried to make puzzles like this in LaTex and had some problems, especially with examples for division .
[image]

With help of \begin{tabular} i make this for addition and multiplication:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{cmap}                   
\usepackage{mathtext}               
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{color,xlop}            

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} 
\usepackage{icomma} 

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} 
\usepackage{euscript}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\newcommand*{\hm}[1]{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}
{\hbox{$\mathsurround=0pt #1$}}{}}

\begin{document} 
  1.
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c}
      & \star & 6 & \star \\
    + &   & \star & 7 \\
        \hline
    \star & \star & 2 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \enspace\enspace
   2.
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c}
     & \star & \star & 0 & 3 \\
    -&  & \star & 8 & \star \\
        \hline
     &  & \star  & 2 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \enspace\enspace
   3.
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c}
    & & & 3& \star&
    & & \times& \star& \star&
    \hline
    & & 2 & 6 & \star&
    & +& \star&\star & &
    \hline
    &\star & \star&2 & 6&
    \end{tabular}
    \enspace\enspace
\end{document}
```

(https://www.overleaf.com/5925286442cbqgdymmxbwc) - compiled version in overleaf.

It looks ok, but not good as i want. It will be ideal if there is a possibility to change some numbers in xlop commands , like /opadd because them looks amazing. In documentation of xlop i found nothing about changing symbols in result.

Is it possible to change numbers with asterisk or letters in xlop operation? If it's not, what is the best way to make division like in image in Latex?

UP.1: Thank you Chtistophe!  xlop with dots looks perfectly:

```
\usepackage{color,xlop}  

\newcommand\hole[1]{$\bullet$}

\opdiv[displayintermediary=all,voperation=top, operandstyle.1.3=\hole,operandstyle.1.2=\hole, operandstyle.2.2=\hole , resultstyle.1=\hole ]{840}{35}
```

But i can't change some numbers in example, like 70 or 140.
Now it looks like this:
[image]

UP.2:

```
\usepackage{color,xlop}  

\newcommand\hole[1]{$\bullet$}

\opdiv[displayintermediary=all,voperation=top, operandstyle.1.3=\hole,operandstyle.1.2=\hole, operandstyle.2.2=\hole ,
intermediarystyle.1.1=\hole,intermediarystyle.1.2=\hole, intermediarystyle.2.1=\hole, intermediarystyle.2.3=\hole, resultstyle.1=\hole ]{840}{35}
```

This code returns:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your example produces many compilation errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you explain the semantics (meaning) of the components of the puzzle that is shown in the image? Without understanding the structure it is difficult to propose a suiteable solution

Comment: Thank you for comment Steven! There is a compilation problem with \item . I cage a code, you could see it in Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/5925286442cbqgdymmxbwc .

Comment: It is a typical French style of vertical division. Also this style is being used in post-soviet countries. This image is a task for primary school, and students should put right numbers instead of stars.

Comment: @gernot Welcome back :-) if you come to Sicily I'll host you but here there are 44 degrees in the morning and afternoon. Ahahahh

Comment: Use `remainderstyle` for the remaining number :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I gladly accept your offer, but because of my thick yeti fur, we have to wait until the next ice age.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\newcommand\hole[1]{$\ast$}
\begin{document}
\opdiv[%
  displayintermediary=all,voperation=top,%
  operandstyle.1.3=\hole,operandstyle.1.2=\hole,%
  operandstyle.2.2=\hole,%
  intermediarystyle.1.1=\hole,intermediarystyle.1.2=\hole,%
  remainderstyle.1.1=\hole,remainderstyle.1.2=\hole,%
  intermediarystyle.2.1=\hole,intermediarystyle.2.3=\hole,%
  resultstyle.1=\hole
]{840}{35}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Why didn't I think of "remainderstyle"... Now everything looks great!

Comment: @AlexandrProshin Well, it is explained in the documentation, as Christophe Poulain pointed out

Answer (score 1):

you can read page 10 of xlop's manuel and use as this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,xlop}
\newcommand\hole[1]{$\bullet$}
\begin{document}
\opdiv[displayintermediary=all,voperation=top, operandstyle.1.3=\hole,operandstyle.1.2=\hole, operandstyle.2.2=\hole , resultstyle.1=\hole, remainderstyle.1=\color{red}\hole, intermediarystyle.1.1=\color{blue}\hole ]{840}{35}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This can definitely do with some explanation rather than just pointing to an external reference. Can you add some more detail to this Christophe... something that shows how you can use [`xlop`](//ctan.org/pkg/xlop) to replicate the current request?

Comment: Thank you Christophe! It works well, but i can't change some numbers in example - \usepackage{color,xlop}  
\newcommand\hole[1]{$\bullet$}
\opdiv[displayintermediary=all,voperation=top, operandstyle.1.3=\hole,operandstyle.1.2=\hole, operandstyle.2.2=\hole , resultstyle.1=\hole ]{840}{35}